# How do I find the parent directory in C#?

Tags: c#, directory, filesystems

I use this code for finding the debug directory

```
public string str_directory = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString();
```

*`"C:\\Users\\Masoud\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\MyProj\\MyProj\\bin\\Debug"`*

How can I find the parent folder as shown below?

*`"C:\\Users\\Masoud\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\MyProj\\MyProj"`*

Comment: Why do people always use ToString() on strings?

Comment: @Hogan, in case the property changes? :D

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can use [`System.IO.Directory.GetParent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) to retrieve the parent directory of a given directory.

Comment: if the directory has trailing slashes, you have to call GetParent twice

Comment: This appears to work on relative paths (happy surprise), but then has no way for you to get the result back (unhappy surprise).

Comment: You can avoid the trailing slashes issue by instead using `DirectoryInfo.Parent`. e.g. `new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("c:/path/to/somewhere//").Parent`. @northben

Comment: `Directory.GetParent(path.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)).FullName`

Answer (score 56):

```
string parent = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(str_directory).FullName;
```

See [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx)

Answer (score 48):

If you append `..\..` to your existing path, the operating system will correctly browse the grand-parent folder.

That should do the job:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\Masoud\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\MyProj\\MyProj\\bin\\Debug", @"..\..");
```

If you browse that path, you will browse the grand-parent directory.

Comment: What exactly I've needed.

Comment: The result of "Path.Combine" can be passed through "Path.GetFullPath" to get it cleaned up. That is to get to "C:\Users\Masoud\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MyProj\MyProj"

Comment: This is the best way to go up several levels in directory tree

Comment: This doesn't work if you want the "parent" directory of a file. (I understand that's not what the poster wanted, but it was why I came here.)

Comment: @supergra of course not. But feel free to use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName` to get the directory of a file

Answer (score 27):

**Edit:** The normalization covered in the answer below only happens when the path is used to access the file system, but not on the string itself. By contrast, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60758267/543814) achieves the result *and* normalization purely using path strings, without using the file system at all.

I've found variants of `System.IO.Path.Combine(myPath, "..")` to be the easiest and most reliable. Even more so if what northben says is true, that `GetParent` requires an extra call if there is a trailing slash. That, to me, is unreliable.

`Path.Combine` makes sure you never go wrong with slashes.

`..` behaves exactly like it does everywhere else in Windows. You can add any number of `\..` to a path in cmd or explorer and it will behave exactly as I describe below.

Some basic `..` behavior:

1. If there is a file name, `..` will chop that off:

`Path.Combine(@"D:\Grandparent\Parent\Child.txt", "..")` => `D:\Grandparent\Parent\`

2. If the path is a directory, `..` will move up a level:

`Path.Combine(@"D:\Grandparent\Parent\", "..")` => `D:\Grandparent\`

3. `..\..` follows the same rules, twice in a row:

`Path.Combine(@"D:\Grandparent\Parent\Child.txt", @"..\..")` => `D:\Grandparent\`
`Path.Combine(@"D:\Grandparent\Parent\", @"..\..")` => `D:\`

4. And this has the exact same effect:

`Path.Combine(@"D:\Grandparent\Parent\Child.txt", "..", "..")` => `D:\Grandparent\`
`Path.Combine(@"D:\Grandparent\Parent\", "..", "..")` => `D:\`

Comment: I agree that this method has the advantage of working whether or not the path has a trailing backslash. And in situations where you want a simple path without the dots in it you can apply Path.GetFullPath(() to the result.

Comment: Two years later and I find myself back here again. Be aware that Path.GetFullPath(() normally returns a path without any trailing backslash, but when you get up to the root directory, for example "E:\", then there is a backslash.

Comment: This doesn't work, neither with .NET 4.7 nor .NET Core 2.1: `Path.Combine(@"D:\Grandparent\Parent\Child.txt", @"..")` = `D:\Grandparent\Parent\Child.txt\..`

Comment: This doesn't truncate the filename for me, at least on MacOS via Unity.

Comment: @Métoule @supergra I see the confusion. `Path.Combine` does not truncate the string itself. _The path_, once used to access the file system, has the intended effect. However, I agree that this is suboptimal. See my [more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875904/how-do-i-find-the-parent-directory-in-c/#answer-60758267) on this page for an approach that modifies the string instead of needing the file system to resolve the path.

Comment: @Métoule to resolve the path you can do this:
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\Masoud\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\MyProj\\MyProj\\bin\\Debug\\", @"..\..", "test.txt")));
    f.DirectoryName;

Comment: This is incorrect. Path.Combine doesn't support handling .. like this. It just preserves .. as is. Check in .net5 or 6. Path.GetFullPath works fine.

Comment: @SalientBrain This was already discussed. See my reply to @Métoule above. TLDR: `Path.Combine` does not truncate the string itself. Rather, the path, once used to access the file system, has the intended effect. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875904/how-do-i-find-the-parent-directory-in-c/#answer-60758267) for a non-deferred alternative (that _also_ does not rely on the file system for building the path).

Answer (score 12):

`Directory.GetParent` is probably a better answer, but for completeness there's a different method that takes string and returns string: [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx).

```
string parent = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(str_directory);
```

Comment: Mind you Path.GetDirectoryName doesnt work well with relative paths.. Directory.GetParent does.

Comment: At the risk of repeating something someone else has already mentioned - bear in mind that Directory.GetParent() actually accesses the file system, Path.GetDirectoryName() is just string manipulation.

Answer (score 11):

To get a 'grandparent' directory, call [Directory.GetParent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) twice:

```
var gparent = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(str_directory).ToString());
```

Comment: `var gparent = Directory.GetParent(str_directory).Parent; // Cleaner?`

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo myDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
string parentDirectory = myDirectory.Parent.FullName;
```

Good luck!

Comment: myDirectory.Parent.ToString() returns the subfolder's name, not the full path, exactly what I was looking for. In addition, instead of doing Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(str_directory).ToString()); as showing above, simply using myDirectory.parent.parent.ToString() gets the 'grandparent'.

Comment: I find this method the best because it handles the case where your directory path has trailing slashes. Whereas if you use Directory.GetParent(), you have to call it twice to remove the slashes and then get the actual parent.

Answer (score 6):

No one has provided a solution that would work cross-form. I know it wasn't specifically asked but I am working in a linux environment where most of the solutions (as at the time I post this) would provide an error.

Hardcoding path separators (as well as other things) will give an error in anything but Windows systems.

In my original solution I used:

```
char filesep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
string datapath = $"..{filesep}..{filesep}";
```

However after seeing some of the answers here I adjusted it to be:

```
string datapath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).FullName).FullName;
```

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look into the [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx).`Parent` property.

Answer (score 4):

```
IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..")
```

If you clear the "`bin\Debug\`" in the Project properties -> Build -> Output path, then you can just use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: This works for current .NET version which is 5 at this time. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Since nothing else I have found helps to solve this in a truly normalized way, here is another answer.

Note that some answers to similar questions try to use the `Uri` type, but that struggles with trailing slashes vs. no trailing slashes too.

My [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29409005/543814) on this page works for operations that put the file system to work, but if we want to have the resolved path right now (such as for comparison reasons), without going through the file system, `C:/Temp/..` and `C:/` would be considered different. Without going through the file system, navigating in that manner does not provide us with a normalized, properly comparable path.

What can we do?

#### We will build on the following discovery:

> `Path.GetDirectoryName(path + "/") ?? ""` will *reliably* give us a directory path *without a trailing slash*.

- Adding a slash (as `string`, *not* as `char`) will treat a `null` path the same as it treats `""`.
- `GetDirectoryName` will refrain from discarding the last path component thanks to the added slash.
- `GetDirectoryName` will normalize slashes and navigational dots.
- This includes the removal of any trailing slashes.
- This includes collapsing `..` by navigating up.
- `GetDirectoryName` will return `null` for an empty path, which we coalesce to `""`.

#### How do we use this?

First, **normalize the input path**:

```
dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dirPath + "/") ?? ""; // To handle nulls, we append "/" rather than '/'
```

Then, we can **get the parent directory**, and we can repeat this operation any number of times to navigate further up:

```
// This is reliable if path results from this or the previous operation
path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Note that we have never touched the file system. No part of the path needs to exist, as it would if we had used `DirectoryInfo`.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid issues with trailing \, call it this way:

```
  string ParentFolder =  Directory.GetParent( folder.Trim('\\')).FullName;
```

Comment: You can use `TrimEnd` if you only want to remove trailing `\`'s . I'm not sure if a leading `\` is significant in other OSes.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I am using .NET 6. When I use:

```
public string str_directory = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString();
```

returns **C:\Projects\MyTestProject\bin\Debug\net6.0**

In order to reach **C:\Projects\MyTestProject** I am using the following:

```
Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent
```

You can chain `Parent` to `Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory)` in order to reach the directory you want.

**Final version:**

```
public string str_directory = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the most common way -- it really depends on what you are doing exactly:
(To explain, the example below will remove the last 10 characters which is what you asked for, however if there are some business rules that are driving your need to find a specific location you should use those to retrieve the directory location, not find the location of something else and modify it.)

```
// remove last 10 characters from a string
str_directory = str_directory.Substring(0,str_directory.Length-10);
```

Comment: Your first only works if you know that the last characters are *exactly* `\bin\Debug`, with no trailing `\` and no other path, so it's extraordinarily fragile. Your second doesn't work because `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is a string, and strings don't have a `Parent` property.

Comment: @Joe, I removed the 2nd.  But I think this is a valid answer, if the path is always \bin\debug it will work.  And as I said the OP should really look at what the BR is that drives the need for the directory and use a different approach (I'd probably use a configuration entry, but I'm guessing at the BR and program structure.)

Comment: While not perfect and fragile, its the only solution that worked for me. Suggested edit:  "str_directory.length" should be "str_directory.Length", lower case L is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

To get your solution 
try this

```
string directory = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).ToString()).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to do that. Environment.CurrentDirectory gives you the path of the executable directory. This is consistent regardless of where the .exe file is. You shouldn't try to access a file that is assumed to be in a backwards relative location

I would suggest you move whatever resource you want to access into a local location. Of a system directory (such as AppData)