# How do I find the parent directory of a path?

Tags: .net

How do I get a parent of a directory, for example:

```
string upDir = GetOneLvlUp(@"C:\AAA\BBB\CCC\DDD\");

Output:  C:\AAA\BBB\CCC\
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the parent directory in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875904/how-do-i-find-the-parent-directory-in-c)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
upDir = Directory.GetParent(path).FullName;
```

Comment: attention: Directory.GetParent(@"C:\AAA\BBB\CCC\DDD\").FullName == @"C:\AAA\BBB\CCC\DDD".

Comment: This is not correct. As @SergejLoos says above this will just remove the slash. We want to do this DirectoryInfo(yourPath).Parent.FullName instead.

Comment: @DezUdezue, I'm not working on .net these days and don't know the changes. But if what you wrote is a .net buit in function then this is inconsistency in .net and you could report it as a bug.

Answer (score 7):

Everything you want is in the Directory class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx

In particular, GetParent:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx

Answer (score 6):

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string parentDir = Directory.GetParent(path).FullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var upDir = new DirectoryInfo(yourPath).Parent.FullName;
```

Comment: It is not right:
upDir = Directory.GetParent(path).FullName;

Because if the path string ends with the character "\", an incorrect parent path may be returned.