# cut last slash and item for path in c#

Tags: c#, split

I would like to cut last slash and corresponding file or folder given path in string variable (called pathVar)

For example, if pathVar = "c:\temp\a\b\c"
I would like to assign to newPathVar = "c:\temp\a\b"

What is the easier and best way in c# to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363234/how-do-i-find-the-parent-directory-of-a-path

Comment: @AzNjoE: Note that the path has to be valid for that answer to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that.

Comment: Try it out, it does. It doesn't care about what's in the file system at all. It just looks at the actual path syntax. The only oddball I found is that it will just strip the trailing slash if given a path like "c:\temp\a\b\". But that doesn't apply in this case, considering the example they gave.

Comment: do you mean like `c:\temp\a\b\ ` should be `c:\temp\a\b` or `c:\temp\a`

Comment: @MatthewWhited, sorry, blame the sometimes-working-and-sometimes-not escaping in comments. It's been corrected now.

Comment: if you just want to drop the slash then use `.TrimEnd('\')`

Comment: Don't worry... I'm half asleep so I thought your comment was from OP saying your solution didn't work :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I commented before I clicked the docs; it'll work with a directory too, apparently.