# Going to parent folder in file explorer written in c# console

Tags: c#, console-application, file-browser

**UPDATED:**

This code will work like a common WindowsFormApplication file explorer.

When you enter the id for each folder (each files and folders will have an id), it will show files and folders in it.

> The thing i want is when user enter the "**..**" console **go one step
>   back** (parent directory). I mean do somthing like "**cd ..**" in CMD

This code will do the exploring in child folders (and its OK) but i don't know how to get back to the parent folder ( i know i should use ***Directory.GetParent*** and i know how to use it, i just want to know where should i put it in the code):

```
        while (true)
        {
            var select2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                var dirDir = Directory.GetDirectories(dirDrive[select2]);
                var fileDir = Directory.GetFiles(dirDrive[select2]);
                for (var j = 0; j < dirDir.Length; j++)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0})\t{1}", j, Path.GetFileName(dirDir[j].TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)));
                for (var k = dirDir.Length; k < fileDir.Length; k++)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0})\t{1}", k, Path.GetFileName(fileDir[k]));

                dirDrive = dirDir;
        }
```

Here you can see the codes that i added (commented codes) but it will crash absolutely because i don't have a folder with id "**..**" in my array, and it will say "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
 while (true)
        {
            var select2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //if (Convert.ToString(select2) != "..")
            //{
                var dirDir = Directory.GetDirectories(dirDrive[select2]);
                var fileDir = Directory.GetFiles(dirDrive[select2]);
                for (var j = 0; j < dirDir.Length; j++)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0})\t{1}", j, Path.GetFileName(dirDir[j].TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)));
                for (var k = dirDir.Length; k < fileDir.Length; k++)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0})\t{1}", k, Path.GetFileName(fileDir[k]));

                dirDrive = dirDir;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    var dirDir = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetDirectoryName(dirDrive[select2]));//Error occurs here
            //    var fileDir = Directory.GetFiles(dirDrive[select2]);
            //    for (var j = 0; j < dirDir.Length; j++)
            //        Console.WriteLine("{0})\t{1}", j, Path.GetFileName(dirDir[j].TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)));
            //    for (var k = dirDir.Length; k < fileDir.Length; k++)
            //        Console.WriteLine("{0})\t{1}", k, Path.GetFileName(fileDir[k]));
            //    dirDrive = dirDir;
            //}
        }
```

This is the whole code: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/CWggXd0U) , in case you want to try it.

MY QUESTION: I use this code for exploring through child folders. I want to know how can i get to parent folder ?

Thanks to all programmers helped me last time.

Comment: `Here i added this lines for the purpose but it will crash and say "Index was outside the bounds of the array."` On which line?

Comment: What **specifically** is the question here? "My code doesn't work, please tell me how to fix it" isn't nearly specific enough. Is the question really about the Index out of bounds exception you get? Are you asking how to take a path and chop off the last part to get its parent? Please be more specific.

Comment: i mean the first line in else{ } and the if{ } itself @mjwills

Comment: @DewinaTwice You may wish to put that into your post, rather than as a comment.

Comment: When the exception is thrown, what is the value of `select2`? Of `dirDrive.Count()`?

Comment: problem is : in the `while{ }` how can i make it to go one step back if user typed 999.

Comment: it shows the number 999. and yes its absolutly out of bound

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the parent directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875904/how-do-i-find-the-parent-directory-in-c)

Comment: thanks for the sugestion, im goin to try it.

Comment: ok thanks i got the idea. but im so stupid, dont know how to use it, trying it will take hours.