# C# How to get current path and go up one folder

Tags: c#, file-io, path

I am able to get the current path through:

```
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
```

For example, it is C:\consoleapp\capp\files

I want to go up one folder to :
 C:\consoleapp\capp\

and then to another folder
 C:\consoleapp\capp\images

How do I do that?

Comment: Check [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.7.2) static methods.

Answer (score 2):

Following should help you to Get to the Parent Directory and then create the new Path based on it.

```
var path = @"C:\consoleapp\capp\files"; // or in your case Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
var parent = Directory.GetParent(path).FullName;
var newPath = Path.Combine(parent,"Images");
```

You can read more details on Directory.GetParent() [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getparent?view=netframework-4.7.2). Path.Combine allows to you combine multiple strings to path. You can read more on Path.Combine [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Output

```
parent = C:\consoleapp\capp
newPath = C:\consoleapp\capp\Images
```

Comment: There is [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6875904/1997232) for that part of question already.

Comment: I was hoping to force you to answer another part too.

Comment: @Sinatr Guess what, I didnt see that part :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use System.IO
You can use `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` and then just use `di.Parent`

Answer (score 0):

From [How to navigate a few folders up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899422/how-to-navigate-a-few-folders-up)

```
string path = @"C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4";
string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, @"..\..\"));
```

After you navigated up you can attach the new folder again

Comment: Why you have deleted the [concat 2 strings question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54570681/concat-2-strings-return-null-if-one-is-empty). It was interesting once it was clear.I have edited it to make it clearer. Undelete it and i can answer