# Search parent directory from DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, io, directoryinfo

Is there any way to search for the particular parent directory?

I know I can get the parent of the directory using this

```
Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).FullName
```

But this returns immediate parent, is there any way I can kind of search for particular parent in the directory hierarchy of the path?

**EDIT**

What I am trying to achieve is, say if I have current directory like this

```
C:/Project/Source/Dev/Database
```

So I want to reach to the directory `Source`
I know I can reach it by calling `GetParent` method twice but this I don't think is the right way to do it because what if in future my file current directory changes and it goes further down.
So I want some full proof way where I can directly find the path of the directory `Source` no matter how deep I am in the current directory because that is for sure that I will be inside directory `Source`

So something like

```
FindParent('Source')
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @stuartd - Added more info

Comment: What should the `FindParent` method return?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - The path of the parent directory I am searching for

Comment: I think you will have to do it "manually". You could have multiples with this name. E.g: C:\project\source\data\source\dev\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I thought there is an already existing way or function but if I have to write it myself then this solution I wrote worked for me

```
    private static string GetParent(string directoryPath, string parent)
    {
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
        while (directory.Parent!=null)
        {
            if (directory.Parent.Name.ToLower() == parent.ToLower())
            {
                return directory.Parent.FullName;
            }

            directory = directory.Parent;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `if (string.Equals(directory.Parent.Name, parent, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))` instead of `if (directory.Parent.Name == parent)` since directory name is *case insensitive*

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Done in a different way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this (`for` loop):

```
private static IEnumerable<String> ParentDirectories(string directory = null) {
  for (string dir = null == directory ? Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() : directory;
       dir != null;
       dir = Directory.GetParent(dir)?.FullName)
    yield return dir;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
var demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  ParentDirectories(@"C:/Project/Source/Dev/Database"));

Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
C:/Project/Source/Dev/Database // initial directory
C:\Project\Source\Dev          // and its all parents
C:\Project\Source
C:\Project
C:\
```

If you don't want to *include* directory itself, add `.Skip(1)`:

```
var demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  ParentDirectories(@"C:/Project/Source/Dev/Database").Skip(1));
```

Finally, if you want to find out a parent directory which ends by `Source`:

```
string dirName = "Source";

string myParent = ParentDirectories(@"C:/Project/Source/Dev/Database")
  .FirstOrDefault(dir => string.Equals(
     dirName,
     new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name, 
     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

Console.Write(myParent);
```

**Outcome:**

```
C:\Project\Source
```

Answer (score 1):

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns a string that represents the full absolute path of the current directory.

If you want to get the path of a specific parent directory, you can simply use `substring`:

```
var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // Suppose C:/Project/Source/Dev/Database
var sourceDir = new string[] {Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Source" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,
                           Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar + "Source" + Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar};

var sourcePath = path.IndexOf(sourceDir[0], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1 ?
    path.Substring(0, path.IndexOf(sourceDir[0]) + sourceDir[0].Length) :
    path.IndexOf(sourceDir[1], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1 ? 
        path.Substring(0, path.IndexOf(sourceDir[1]) + sourceDir[1].Length) : 
        null;
```

I've used `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` as separators so that the code will work the same on each platform.

Comment: @PawanNogariya I've updated my answer. [Now it does work.](https://rextester.com/OKLT62301)

Comment: @stuartd Changed to case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibles without anymore additional information about your situation:

1. [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.7.2) would get you all the child directories of the **Current** directory so you would need to switch your current to the root + 1
2. [System.IO.Path.Combine(myPath, "..")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29409005/11154257) which would act more like `cd ..`

Answer (score 0):

When traversing any kind of sequence (a sequence of numbers, a sequence of directories, a sequence of nodes in a graph), you have the option of employing **recursion**.

Directory structures (when ignoring links of any kind) are a subset of the data structure known as a Directed Acyclic Graph (or DAG) - this subset typically doesn't rejoin and fans out forever (so long as the operating system allows for the given depth of your nested directories). We typically refer to this as a **Tree** structure.

When put in this light, its probably no surprise to most that the concept of recursion surfaces because its quite common for programmers to apply recursion to traverse down a tree. However, whether you traverse up or down a tree is simply an implementation detail.

There is no reason you cannot use recursion to also traverse up a tree.

Here is a simple console app (written using .net6 conventions & C#10 syntax) that you can study, and then perhaps apply to solve future problems.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // For the [Optional] attribute

var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var file = Directory.GetFiles(dir).First();
var projFile = DirectoryRecursor.RecurseUpwardsUntilFileIsFoundWith(".csproj", file, 5);
Console.WriteLine(projFile);


public static class DirectoryRecursor
{
    public static FileInfo? RecurseUpwardsUntilFileIsFoundWith(
        string stringToMatch,
        string sourceFile,
        [Optional] int? maxParentDirLevel)
    {
        if (maxParentDirLevel is not null && maxParentDirLevel == 0) return null; // try and stave off disaster

        var dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFile);
        if (dirName is null) return null;

        var csprojFile = Directory.GetFiles(dirName).Where(x => x.EndsWith(stringToMatch)).SingleOrDefault();
        if (csprojFile is null)
        {
            if (ThereIsAParentDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(sourceFile), out var parentDir))
            {
                return RecurseUpwardsUntilFileIsFoundWith(stringToMatch, parentDir.FullName, maxParentDirLevel - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return new FileInfo(csprojFile);
    }

    public static bool ThereIsAParentDirectory(DirectoryInfo dir, out DirectoryInfo parentDir)
    {
        if (dir.Parent is not null)
        {
            parentDir = dir.Parent;
            return dir.Parent.Exists;
        }

        parentDir = dir;
        return false;
    }
}
```

A quick side note:

An example of applied recursion both up and down a tree (which I appologize is not currently open source), is the conversation builder over at [www.palavyr.com](https://www.palavyr.com). This conversation tree is implemented as a double linked list to facilitate recursion both up and down the conversation tree. I'm planning on producing a technical blog post explaining this implementation -  I'll update this response with that once I've assembled it.