# How to get one up level folder name from a string?

Tags: c#, winforms

for exmaple if the path in the string textBoxRadarPath.txt is D:\test\test1\test2
i want to get only the part D:\test

using root is not what i needed root give me D:\ but i want to first path level.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetPathRoot(textBoxPath.Text) + "\\" + urlsListFolder);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6875904/1623971

Comment: Check out that answer to get your parent directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the parent directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875904/how-do-i-find-the-parent-directory-in-c)

Comment: Path.GetPathRoot(path) to get the base Path!

Comment: `var uri = new Uri(path); string first2Segments = Path.Combine(uri.Segments[1], uri.Segments[2]);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
public string GetFirstLevel(string Path)
    {
        string[] Segments = Path.Split(Convert.ToChar(@"\"));

        return Segments[0] + @"\" + Segments[1];
    }
```

And here is an example of it's usage:

```
public void Test()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GetFirstLevel(@"D:\test\test1\test2")); //It will return: D:\test
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
string path = @"D:\test\test1\test2";
var Levels = path.Select((b, i) => b.Equals('\\') ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToList();

string newPath = path.Substring(0, Levels [1]);
Console.WriteLine(newPath);
```

result:

> D:\test